Adding a CNAME record to a customer subdomain
My Laravel app allows customers to create their own subdomains using the framework's built-in subdomain routing:
Route::domain('{domain}.example.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/user/{id}', function (string $account, string $id) {
        // ...
    });
});

I would also like allow my customers to add CNAMEs to use their own custom domains, e.g. "initech.com" has a CNAME record pointed to "initech.example.com."
However, I've added a test CNAME record, but when I visit "initech.com," I'm served the main page of "example.com," and not the "initech.example.com" page that I was expecting.
I think that this is a server configuration issue, and that I need to make an update to my Nginx configuration to tell it how to properly serve content from "initech.com."
My current Nginx configuration is the default created by Laravel Forge:
# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/example.com/before/*;


server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com *.example.com
    server_tokens off;
    root /home/forge/example.com/public;
    

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/12345/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/12345/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128...;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/example.com/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}


# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/example.com/after/*;



I'm I on right path? Can I modify the Nginx config above to accept traffic from "initech.com" and handle it as expected?
